# Save cookie when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I have this code

```
<script>
    function saver(page) {
        document.cookie = 'page='+page;
        <? $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_COOKIE['page']; ?>
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

And I want to execute it when the button is pressed here

```
<div class="xmenu">
    <div class="parent2">
    <div class="test1"><a href="pics/categories.png"><img src="pics/categories.png"></a></i></div>
    <div class="test2"><a href="pics/user.png"><img src="pics/user.png"></a></i></div>
    <div class="test3"><a href="pics/bookmarks.png"><img src="pics/bookmarks.png"></a></i></div>
    <div class="test4"><a href="pics/search.png"><img src="pics/search.png"></a></i></div>
    <div class="test5"><a href="../../../HOME/demo[ENTRA%20QUI]/new%20%201.html"><img src="pics/home.png"></a></i></div>
    <div class="test6"><a href="javascript:saver();" onClick="saver()"><img src="pics/backup.png"></a></i></div> <--- here the button
    <div class="mask2"><img src="pics/etor.jpg"></a></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function is in the head. The "page" variable (in javascript)... well I don't know where is defined but I see it's used after the menu (that's in the body).
Can someone help me?

Comment: And what is the problem? (Except that you don't pass any value to `saver()` and named `onclick` `onClick`)?

Comment: You seem to be confusing server-side with client-side scripting. I'd suggest you read a bit more into it to help clarify some concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following. A very simple form with a button and a function to set the cookie in PHP.

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // Set the cookie
    setcookie("TestCookie", "SomethingSomethingSomething", time()+3600);  /* expire in 1 hour */
}
?>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <button type="submit">Create that cookie already!!!</button>
</form>">
```

Answer (score 4):

It is impossible to do with your code. Because when your page will be loaded, this code:

```
<script>
    function saver(page) {
        document.cookie = 'page='+page;
        <? $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_COOKIE['page']; ?>
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

will be rendered once and It will look like this:

```
<script>
    function saver(page) {
        document.cookie = 'page='+page;
        return null;
    }
</script>
```

When user clicks will call saver() function, your server doesn't receive any data. To do that, you have to use ajax (from jQuery for example).

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function saver(page) {
        document.cookie = 'page='+page;
        return null;

        $.ajax({

            url: 'http://example.com/your_script.php',
            method: 'get',
            success: function(response) {

                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**your_script.php**

```
<?
    $_SESSION['pagina'] = $_COOKIE['page'];

    return 'ok';
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/ The alert doesn't appear and it seems that the variable hasn't been passed.